# Read import.meta from imported ES modules

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

[`import.meta`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta) returns information about the current module. The [spec](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-meta#will-this-object-be-locked-down-in-any-way) says this object is extensible:

> The committee's tentative decision [that] by default the import.meta object will be extensible, and its properties will be writable, configurable, and enumerable.
>
> There is no real benefit to locking down the object, as it is local to the module, and can only be shared explicitly by passing it around. It does not represent "global state" or anything of the sort.

If I define a property on Module A's `import.meta`:

```js
// module A

import.meta.test = "hello";

export default () => {};
```

Can I read that property when I import Module A? If so, how?

```js
import moduleA from "./module-a.js";

console.log(moduleA.meta); // undefined

// or...

async function () {
  const moduleA = import("./module-a.js");

  console.log(moduleA.meta); // undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own quote says it all:

> as it is local to the module, and can only be shared explicitly by passing it around.

Comment: I read "sharing explicitly" as "importing". My mental model is that a module is a box and that `import.meta` is a sticker on the box containing details about the box... so in that analogy, shouldn't I be able to read that sticker in some other context?

Comment: No you cannot, you need to explicitly still export it. Also why would you need this? You're defining a new property, just export it. You can even export something called `meta` if you like.

Comment: Ok, I guess the language tripped me up a bit. As for the why, I'm experimenting with a testing framework.